# docker: why Failed to connect to seed

Tags: docker, aerospike

I run the following docker command. I don't understand why it is failed. Could you show me how to debug this? Thanks.

```
$ docker run -v `pwd`:/share -ti --name aerospike-aql --rm aerospike/aerospike-tools aql --host 192.168.1.191 --no-config-file
Unable to find image 'aerospike/aerospike-tools:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from aerospike/aerospike-tools
6ec7b7d162b2: Pull complete 
177617b11d13: Pull complete 
10273812b9e3: Pull complete 
ac553cdb1df6: Pull complete 
d633ea8cb425: Pull complete 
1f91817a9ef3: Pull complete 
403620a9a728: Pull complete 
3a80741c7bbc: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:109801d7e8440dcf53461b13b55eaa96c1f86482209691285a34c6bb2fee4e1d
Status: Downloaded newer image for aerospike/aerospike-tools:latest
Seed:         192.168.1.191
User:         None
Config File:  None
2021-01-16 02:46:44 WARN Failed to connect to seed 192.168.1.191 3000. AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Socket write error: 111, 192.168.1.191:3000
Error -10: Failed to connect
```

Comment: Do you have an Aerospike Server running on 192.168.1.191 port 3000? If so double check the logs on that instance to verify it's running.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Micah's comment I can suggest running again the server image, and then the command below that is not using the hardcoded host IP 192.168.1.191 but rather pulls it from the settings:

```
$ docker run --rm -tid --name aerospike -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -p 3002:3002 -p 3003:3003 aerospike/aerospike-server


$ docker run -v `pwd`:/share -ti --name aerospike-aql --rm aerospike/aerospike-tools aql --host $(docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' aerospike) --no-config-file
```